# Cisco ISE REST HttpUrlConnection 400 Bad Request with POST and xml in body

Tags: java, xml, httpurlconnection, cisco, bad-request

I'm currently working on a program that takes 4 values(MAC, Policy, IdentityGroup and description) from a csv file and writes them to a Cisco ISE as Endpoint.

The user credentials and URL are aquired via a little GUI.

First I'm checking if the IdentityGroups given in the file are valid via a GET Request that works just fine and return a Map of Group IDs mapped to Groupnames.

Then I try to create the Endpoint by sending a POST Request with the required information as XML in the Body:

```
URL readURL = new URL(url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + ":" + 

url.getPort() + "/ers/config/Endpoint");
HttpURLconnection con;
con = (HttpURLConnection) readURL.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password.getBytes("utf-8")));
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.Endpoint.1.0.xml");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.Endpoint.1.0+xml");
con.setDoOutput(true)
con.setDoInput(true);
con.connect();

System.out.println("All Properties set.");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

System.out.println("Got Outputstream.");

System.out.println("The entry to write: "+e.toString());

writer.write("<ns3:endpoint name=\"" + e.getMAC()
        + "\" id=\"12341234-12341234-asdasdf-12341\" description=\"" + e.getDescription()
        + "\" xmlns:ns2=\"ers.ise.cisco.com\" xmlns:ns3=\"identity.ers.ise.cisco.com\"><groupId>"
        + groupIDs.get(e.getEndpointIdentifyGroup())    
        + "</groupId><identityStore></identityStore><identityStoreId></identityStoreId><mac>" + e.getMAC()      
        + "</mac><portalUser></portalUser><profileId></profileId><staticGroupAssignment>true</staticGroupAssignment><staticProfileAssignment>false</staticProfileAssignment>");

writer.flush();

System.out.println("MAC " + e.getMAC() + " was sent.");
writer.close();

System.out.println("All entries were written.");

System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
```

Console Output:

```
All Properties set.
Got Outputstream.
The entry to write: CSVEntry [endpointPolicy=StringProperty [value: test], endpointIdentifyGroup=StringProperty [value: test], MAC=StringProperty [value: 11:11:11:11:11:11], description=StringProperty [value: tes>_phe]]
MAC 11:11:11:11:11:11 was sent.
All entries were written.
Bad Request
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://193.186.11.135:9060/ers/config/Endpoint
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
.....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://193.186.11.135:9060/ers/config/Endpoint
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
....
```

I've tried multiple things such as different headers, writing in multiple lines, checking the values like 500 times but I have no idea why I am getting a 400 Bad Request Response.

The other thing that I tried aswell is checking if the Request would be correct by using Postman and sending the POST Request with the exact same headers and the exact same body to the Server and it works (getting 201 Created and it shows in DB).

I hope someone can help me as I don't know what to do, I was googling around checking for solutions but all that I tried didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your much appreciated help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, I found the mistake and I'm ashamed. I forgot to close the xml body with

```
</ns3:endpoint>
```

so it didn't work. It is now working perfectly fine.